# Communication between a process and the bash process opening it

Tags: c, linux, bash, process

I want to build an application that features a shell, which would have a number of custom commands, but I also would like to let users do whatever they can do in their own shell. So I decide against implementing a shell myself. Instead, I want the process to send user input to the stdin of the shell and fetch stdout and stderr of the shell back to the process and print them out. What is the best way to do this? Do I have to write to /proc//fd/0 , or can I do with pipes?

Comment: Read the user input, if it is a custom command then process it, else pass it to the shell via [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)

Comment: I don't want to do that because it seems there are a lot to do such as signal processing. Also, I will be working with ssh and it might be useful to be able to switch file descriptors. Also, `system()` seems to be blocking.

Comment: Then your question is incomplete and too broad. How can we even start to suggest "the best way" when we don't have the full requirements? If you don't want to use `system` then you can implement your own `fork+dup+exec` logic.

Comment: Would that work with an already running process? I feel maybe I need to spawn another shell or something.

Comment: Yes, you spawn another shell per command. Which is what `system` does or what you can do with `fork+dup+exec`.